# Regex search can't find phrases

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract some information from a text file, which looks like as below:

```
# Automated:
% const=.3

VARIABLES
     DOMAIN= 0 2.0 TRANSITION=1,10 DESTINATION=11,16 PARTIAL=0
```

I want to read the TRANSITION and DESTINATION values from this file and store each pair in variables `transition` and `destination`. I am new to regex, so I blindly tried to modify the examples, to start from somewhere, and tried this:

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    line=f.readlines
    line=str(line)

searchObj1 = re.search(r'TRANSITION', line)
searchObj2 = re.search(r'DESTINATION', line)

transition=[searchObj1]
destination=[searchObj2]

if searchObj1:
   print("Transition level inputs: ", searchObj.group())
else:
   print("Transition levels are missing!")

if searchObj2:
   print("Destionation inputs: ", searchObj.group())
else:
   print("Destination values are missing!")
```

But this code can't read the necessary information and returns values are missing. How can I improve this?

PS: I don't have to store the numbers as two pairs, I can also store them as four individual variables.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code, starting with the file reading, the actual regex, and the `.group` call. I recommend you fix one issue at a time, using a debugger to help. If you want to learn regex, I recommend following a regex tutorial (eg. [this one](https://regexone.com/)) instead of blindly modifying examples from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a few more examples and tutorials, I came up with the solution I wanted:

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match1 = re.search(r'TRANSITION=(\S+)', line)
        match2 = re.search(r'DESTINATION=(\S+)', line)
        if match1:
            Trans = match1.group(1)
            print('Transition states: {}'.format(Trans))
        if match2:
            Dest = match2.group(1)
            print('Destination states: {}'.format(Dest))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the values, where t.txt is your text file.

```py
def test_rx(text):
    import re

    res=re.search(r'TRANSITION=(.*)\s+DESTINATION=(.*)\s+PARTIAL',text)
    v1=res.groups()
    return v1

final=[]
with open('t.txt','r') as file:
    lst_text=file.read().splitlines()
    for i in lst_text:
        if 'TRANSITION' in i:
            res=test_rx(i)
            final.append(res)

print(final)


#('1,10', '11,16')
```

Comment: Nice answer, but it will be better if you can exclude the trailing whitespace.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need to read the file instead of defining `text`.